# Converting multiple strings into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, url-routing

I'm trying to make a fancy router, the idea is the following:

`'{subdomain}.{request type}.{uri}' => '{controller}@{method}'`

and what I have so far is this:

**routes.php**

```
return [
    '.GET.'                 => 'home@index',
    '.GET.user/*'           => 'user@viewProfile',
    '.GET.user/*/comments'  => 'user@viewComments',
];
```

**Router.php**

```
class Router {
    private $routes, $uri, $subdomain;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->routes    = $this->parseRoutes(require 'app/routes.php');
        $this->subdomain = $this->getSubdomain();
        $this->uri       = $this->getUri();
    }

    private function getSubdomain() {
        $url = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        return (count($url) >= 3) ? current($url) : '';
    }

    private function getUri() {
        $uri = preg_replace('#\/{2,}#', '/', urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        return trim(str_replace(' ', '', $uri), '/');
    }

    private function parseRoutes($routes) {
        $return = [];
        foreach($routes as $route => $controller) {
            $route = explode('.', $route);
            $uri = explode('/', $route[2]);
            $return[$route[0]][$route[1]][$route[2]] = $controller;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    public function getController() {

    }

}
```

The `parseRoutes` method needs to convert the array into this:

```
[
    '' => [
        'GET' => [
            '' => 'home@index',

            'user' => [
                '*' => [
                    ''         => 'user@viewProfile',
                    'comments' => 'user@viewComments'
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ],
]
```

I can get the `subdomain` and `request type` to work properly, however I have no idea how to convert the uri into a format like that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can get the requested subdomain and type, but you don't know how to convert the uri into such a format? Have you tried thinking about which parts needs to be where and how you could possible get there?

Comment: The array from `routes.php` needs to get converted into the example I've given at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $controller = 'home';
protected $method = 'index';
protected $params = [];
public function __construct(){
this->parseUrl();
// also add if statements to check if controller, method exist

// CHECK IF PARAMETERS EXIST, IF YES, GET ARRAY OF PARAMENTERS, OTHERWISE SET   EMPTY ARRAY
$this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);

} // end of constructor
// SPLITTING URL INTO ARRAY (url[0] / url[1] / url[2] / ...)
// A.K.A.(controller/method/property1/property2/...)
public function parseUrl(){
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} // end of if
} // end of function parseUrl
```

Comment: I don't think this will help OP.